# python selenium the wait.to_be_clickable() method cannot be clicked immediately

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am writing a test script to click buttons that are dynamically inserted using ajax. However, after the script use the wait.element_to_be_clickable method, the final element turned out to be not able to be clicked.
The code looks something like this:

```py
element1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#element_1")))
element2 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#element_2")))
element3 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#element_3")))
element4 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#element_4")))

elements =[element1,element2,element3,element4]
for element in elements:
    element.click()

submit_button = wait.until(EC..element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#element_5")))
submit_button.click()
```

The terminal jumped out an error message, saying that:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input id="fsSubmitButton3988487" class="fsSubmitButton" style="" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> is not clickable at point (509, 688). Other element would receive the click: <b>...</b>
```

I tried using the debugger to run through the script, and it works.
I also tried adding

```py
time.sleep(2)
```

before the last line of code, and it also worked.
Why is the first method not working?

Answer (score 0):

Element is located but Click is being intercepted, it happens when there pop up look for popup or some notification bar that is blocking the click...

Comment: I checked, and there are no pop-ups in the page when I ran the script.

Comment: Post html of source page